# Entity reference widget

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, 8

I know that in Drupal 8 the taxonomy term reference is deprecated and it's implemented by an entity reference in Drupal 8 Core.

Is there any widget to select items by checkbox list instead of the default autocomplete entity reference widget?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes!!

1. Go to Manage form display of the content type
2. Go to the entity reference field and there you can find a list of options including checkbox .

Comment: Still I think I am in Drupal 7 :D.tnx

Comment: If you tag the question with [tag:8] users will think it is about Drupal 8.

Comment: @kiamlaluno sorry, it was miss typing.

Answer (score 5):

### Drupal 8

Go to the *Manage form display* tab.

[image]

### Drupal 7

Go to *Manage fields* tab, and click on the blue widget link.

[image]

It takes you a new page, where you can change the widget to *Check boxes/radio buttons*.

[image]